# How to register input field reference in one component, to a custom Hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I started learning React recently, I have doubt like, I have a signup component which contains a form with Input elements. Also i have a custom hook, which i want to use for carrying validation of input fields. Is there any way to passing reference of input fields to the Custom Hook?

Comment: Here's an [example of custom hook for forms](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-hook-for-forms-in-react-jy0wl). It takes an object representation of a form and then renders the inputs and also performs the validation of the input elements in the form. It might be more complicated for your use case but it will give you an idea of how to create a custom hook to manage forms in react.

Comment: May you share an example of what you're talking about?